# Websocket HTML5 ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a very basic HTML5 page that connects to a websocket from javascript using :

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5555");
```

I always get that error in FF10 : ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
I've check the about:config and WebSockets are enabled.. What's going on??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Firefox supports prefixed version, `MozWebSocket`.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox supports web sockets prefix-free starting from version 11. [here is the release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/11.0/releasenotes/)